# колонки не работают в safari

Tags: css, bootstrap, safari

Сайт [http://azhur.h1n.ru/catalog/Качели](http://azhur.h1n.ru/catalog/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8) работает в большинстве браузеров. В Safari 5.1.4 колонки не переносятся на другую строку и выезжают за границы экрана. Это видно при масштабировании. Что делать?

Comment: А можно поинтересоваться, зачем вам нужно поддерживать устаревшие браузеры?

Comment: Присоединяюсь -  сетка не работает в safari и вообще на  apple-устройствах. У меня аналогичная проблема. Bootstrap 4